# Expressão regular para recuperar strings que começam com dois pontos (:)

Tags: java, string, regex

Preciso de uma expressão regular para recuperar uma lista de *strings* que iniciam pelo caractere dois pontos (":") e finalizam pelo caractere espaço ou fim de parênteses (")").

Exemplo:

```
String texto = "(:TEXTOQUALQUER NADA DO FOI :TEXTOQQDENOVO SERÁ DE NOVO :TEXTOQQMAIS DO JEITO QUE UM DIA :TEXTO3343)";
```

#### Observação

Não há um padrão para as "palavras-chave", as palavras que são acompanhadas pelo caractere dois pontos; elas tem tamanho variado e são sucedidas de espaço em branco ou fim de parênteses como já mencionado. Como posso obter **somente** a lista destas *strings*?

#### Resultado esperado

[TEXTOQUALQUER, TEXTOQQDENOVO, TEXTOQQMAIS, TEXTO3343]

Comment: Sugestão: https://regex101.com/r/dM1vW1/2

Comment: Usualmente _Regex_ para este tipo de coisa é um exagero. Aliás, _Regex_ é aquela coisa que só devia ser usada quando realmente foram esgotadas as possibilidades normais de solução para o problema.

Comment: @Bacco Concordo que é exagero, entretanto fica a ressalva que dependendo do caso seu uso pode ser a forma mais robusta de tratar a entrada. Afinal, o que é texto? **Qualquer** caractere exceto `:` e `)`? Ou há mais envolvido? Na impossibilidade de fazer um *parse* completo (que pode ser ainda mais *overkill* que usar regex) essa técnica ajuda a isolar pequenos fragmentos simples dentro de uma estrutura complexa - sem ter que pra isso interpretar toda essa estrutura.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Nesse caso não consigo imaginar nenhuma razão pra Regex, sinceramente. Se tratam de 2 delimitadores simples e estáticos, é só ir avançando o ponteiro pro seguinte (coisa que o regex vai ter que fazer, de qq forma). Se bem que em se tratando de java, pode até ser capaz que o regex seja mais eficiente, dada a "consistência" com que cada coisa é implementada internamente... PS: Mas acho perfeitamente válidas  respostas atendendo a vontade do OP, diga-se de passagem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A expressão [sugerida pelo Sergio nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43717/express%C3%A3o-regular-para-recuperar-strings-que-come%C3%A7am-com-dois-pontos#comment86920_43717) parece ser a maneira mais simples, salvo pelo `"` (que não foi mencionado na pergunta), e pelo espaço em branco faltante (como apontado por Gustavo Cinque nos comentários). Minha sugestão é utilizá-la para encontrar todos os casamentos:

```
List<String> resultado = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(":([^:\\) ]+)").matcher(texto);
while ( m.find() )
    resultado.add(m.group(1));
```

> **Nota:** minha resposta anterior (em arquivo) não se aplica nesse caso, primeiro porque não é mais necessário usar o `trim` (a string já não contém espaços em branco), segundo porque não é necessário remover os espaços do meio (idem).

Comment: O RegEx não vai funcionar... Está salvando as variaveis e retornando este resultado: `[TEXTOQUALQUERNADADOFOI, TEXTOQQDENOVOSERÁDENOVO, TEXTOQQMAISDOJEITOQUEUMDIA, TEXTO3343]`. É só acrescentar um espaço (`Pattern.compile(":([^:) ]+)")`) depois do `)` e antes do `]`. Testei aqui e funciona.
Ah, não tem como colocar uma barra sozinha dentro de RegEx, pois o `compile()` espera que todas as barras sejam seguidas de  `\b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ `

Comment: E esse forEach tá estranho tambem, hein?

Comment: @GustavoCinque Valeu pelas correções! De fato eu havia interpretado mal o resultado esperado, pensei que fosse todo o texto até o próximo `:` (mas de fato não, é só até o próximo espaço mesmo). Quanto ao `forEach`, quando você conhece muitas linguagens sempre acaba confundindo uma com outra hehe...

Comment: Normal, quando coloquei aqui no IDE, nem tinha percebido, pra mim tava certo tambem =)

Comment: @mgibsonbr, a resposta está perfeita. A motivação para a criação desta pergunta surgiu a partir da necessidade de recuperar os "parâmetros nomeados" de uma sql dentro de uma string. Exemplo: select * from tb_aluno where nome in :nome and sexo = :sexo.

Answer (score 1):

Resposta sem usar RegEx:

```
import java.util.*;
 
class Program {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String texto = "(:TEXTOQUALQUER NADA DO FOI :TEXTOQQDENOVO SERÁ DE NOVO :TEXTOQQMAIS DO JEITO QUE UM DIA :TEXTO3343)";
        List<String> textos = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (texto.length() > 0) {
            texto = texto.substring(texto.indexOf(":") + 1);
            int posicaoParentese = texto.indexOf(")");
            int posicaoEspaco = texto.indexOf(" ");
            int posicaoFinal = Math.min((posicaoParentese == -1 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : posicaoParentese), (posicaoEspaco == -1 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : posicaoEspaco));
            textos.add(texto.substring(0, posicaoFinal));
            texto = texto.substring(posicaoFinal + 1);
        }
        for (String item : textos) System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/T0Qymo). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fejhttym-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/Pattern1.java).

---

<sup>Vou deixar as tentativas anteriores para ajudar quem tenha um problema semelhante. A pergunta estava bastante confusa obrigando as respostas (não só minhas) serem editadas para chegar no resultado desejado. Espero que agora esteja ok.</sup>

Lendo melhor sua pergunta acho que você quer outra coisa, acho que seria só istoL

```
import java.util.*;

class Program {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String texto = "(:TEXTOQUALQUER NADA DO FOI :TEXTOQQDENOVO SERÁ DE NOVO :TEXTOQQMAIS DO JEITO QUE UM DIA :TEXTO3343)";
        List<String> textos = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (texto.length() > 0) {
            texto = texto.substring(texto.indexOf(":") + 1);
            int posicaoParentese = texto.indexOf(")");
            int posicaoEspaco = texto.indexOf(" ");
            int posicaoFinal = Math.min((posicaoParentese == -1 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : posicaoParentese), (posicaoEspaco == -1 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : posicaoEspaco));
            textos.add(texto.substring(0, posicaoFinal));
            texto =  texto.substring(posicaoFinal + 1);
        }
        for (String item : textos) System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OXmzmg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tdccbjfw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/Pattern2.java).

Se ainda não foi respondido, você não precisa de RegEx para isto, basta um [`Split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
class Program {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String texto = "(:TEXTOQUALQUER NADA DO FOI :TEXTOQQDENOVO SERÁ DE NOVO :TEXTOQQMAIS DO JEITO QUE UM DIA :TEXTO3343)";
        String[] textos = texto.split(":");
        for (String item : textos) System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Sfj7G0). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rqtyiwci-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/Pattern3.java).

Se não quer o que vem antes do primeiro `:` basta ignorar o elemento 0 do *arryay* (textos[0]).